# Upgraded to Xcode 4.1 and sqlite3.h is causing compilation errors where it didn't before the upgrade

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I recently opened an existing project from a time before I installed Xcode 4.1.
At first there were many errors and I corrected the problem by chosing LLVM 2.1 as the option for the compiler.
All of the errors but one have been cleared up, in sqlite3.h this line is causing a problem:

SQLITE_API int sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(int) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_5_0);

The error message reads:

Expected function body after function declarator.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: How does the `__OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED()` macro resolve? I assume it is an sqlite3 defined macro. I am a bit surprised by the `__IPHONE_5_0` define.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same problem. I changed my code which said

```
#include "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
```

to

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

and that fixed it. Perhaps you are picking up the wrong header file somehow.

Comment: Very helpful, you are. Is there a reason behind this?

Comment: You can also change the line in the header file to comment out the OSX warning part and it will work: `SQLITE_API int sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(int);// __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_5_0);`

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. Opened an old project in latest Xcode.
sqllite3.h causing errors.

I noticed if you click on the sqlite3.h in your code that caused the error and  open it in xcode, the right click and show in finder you get

```
/usr/include/sqlite3.h
```

yet when you go to the dylib

```
 Project > Targets > Project Name > Build Phases tab > Link Binary with Library section > libsqlite3.lib > right click and Show in Finder
```

you get

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.lib
```

and the headers for this are in a parallel folder

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/include/sqllite3.h
```

more importantly the .h files were different versions

The one in the iPhone SDk dir was

```
#define SQLITE_VERSION        "3.7.2"
```

The one in the Mac /usr/include

```
#define SQLITE_VERSION        "3.7.5"
```

in /usr/include  SQLITE_VERSION "3.7.5" the macro throwing the error is defined
__OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED

```
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(int) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_5_0);
```

But In The one in the iPhone SDk 4.3 / sqlite "3.7.2"

```
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(int);
```

for same definition its not.

the fix mentioned above works

```
 CHANGE EVERY #include "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
```

to

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

Comment: I used Delta Walker to compare the .h files

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I did read somewhere that upgrading to Xcode 4.2 may fix this bug. However, Xcode 4.2 is not currently an approved deployment tool for the App Store, so that's not an option.